# Calculate running profit from average purchase rate and sale rate

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to calculate my profit, product stock quantity and value from purchase and sale.
Suppose my purchase table as

[image]

and my sale table as

[image]

Currently I had done it successfully using php. But because of I am having over 100k purchase and sale, it is working very slowly. So I need to get a mysql solution. The following table describes my profit/stock calculation method.

[image]

> 1. merge purchase and sale and then sort in date wise.
> 2. Balance stock value depends only average purchase rate, not sale rate.
> 3. profit = (sold rate - average purchase rate) * sold quantity

So I need to get when I take the Report of 2017-11-23

> - Profit = 602.38
> - Stock Quantity = 110
> - Stock Value = 9052.3806

Which will be a fast working method to get the above result, a simple select query or using stored procedure/function? if it is better a simple query, how should be it?

Comment: So, at the end, you want to show a daily report for each product. Am I right?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: On the above table I used only one product to easily understand you what I need. But in my real case there will be thousands of products. So the result should be grouped by product id as I get the total profit, quantity and value of each products between the two given dates. For example report between 2017-01-01 to 2017-03-31.

Comment: I have added my database in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7ed28/1

Comment: I think you previously commented that you want Net profit and not the profit for each product.

Comment: According to the above sample-table that was net profit, but in real case there will be more products, and so profit,quantity, and value of each. I need to get a result array as array(0=> [product = 'Book'], [quantity = 100], [value = 1000][profit = 600], 1 =>  [product = 'Pen'], [quantity = 50], [value = 750][profit = 320])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time, you've commented about wanting result for each `Product_id`, I almost done with my solution for displaying `Net Profit`,`Stock Quantity` and `Stock value` within given timeframe.

Hence, I am sharing my approach here anyway as It may be helpful to you or someone else who'll try to solve this problem.

**Solution:**

```
select
       final.profit,
       final.Balance_Stock_Quantity,
       final.Balance_Stock_Value
from
(
select tmp.date_,
       tmp.`Sale/Purchase`,
       tmp.product_id,
       tmp.quantity,
       tmp.rate,
       tmp.val,          
(
  case when tmp.`Sale/Purchase` = 'purchase' 
            then (@total_quant := @total_quant + tmp.quantity)
       else      (@total_quant := @total_quant - tmp.quantity)
  end
) as Balance_Stock_Quantity,
(
  case when tmp.`Sale/Purchase` = 'purchase' 
            then (@total_val := @total_val + tmp.val)
       else      (@total_val := @total_val - (@total_rate*tmp.quantity))
  end
) as Balance_Stock_Value,
(
  case when tmp.`Sale/Purchase` = 'purchase' 
            then (@total_rate := @total_val/@total_quant) 
       else @total_rate
  end
) as Balance_Stock_Rate,
(
  case when tmp.`Sale/Purchase` = 'sale' 
            then (@profit := (tmp.rate - @total_rate)*tmp.quantity) 
       else @profit
  end
) as profit

from
(
(select p_date as date_,
       'Purchase' as `Sale/Purchase`,
       p_product_id as product_id,
       p_quantity as quantity,
       p_rate as rate,
       (p_quantity * p_rate) as val
from purchase
where p_date BETWEEN '2017-11-23 00:00:00' AND '2017-11-23 05:00:00'
)
union all
(select s_date as date_,
       'Sale' as `Sale/Purchase`,
       s_product_id as product_id,
       s_quantity as quantity,
       s_rate as rate,
       (s_quantity * s_rate) as val
from sales
where s_date BETWEEN '2017-11-23 00:00:00' AND '2017-11-23 05:00:00' 
)
)tmp
cross join
(select 
        @total_quant := 0,
        @total_val := 0,
        @total_rate := 0, 
        @profit := 0) r
order by tmp.date_
)final
order by final.date_ desc
limit 1
;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54986/2/0)

**Note 1:** I started to solve this problem with a lot of excitement as I found this a challenging one, but at the end I felt that I am basically doing the same thing which you've already done with some Programming language (for example,task like `case...when` and using variables to maintain **previous** values of `Profit`,`Quantity` etc.

So I am really not sure, how this will efficient than your current approach, but I guess it's still worth a try.

**Note 2:** If your goal is to display Profit, Stocks and Values for **each** product, I think you should stick with your current approach.

Although, It'll make your task easy if you store `Total quantity`, `Rate` and `Total value` (shown in 2nd image in your question) for each product in your `Purchase` and `Sales` table itself. Calculate and store these values while inserting other values in these tables if it's **affordable** for you. This will save a lot of time and effort when you write query for Final Report.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am studying your query. But when I tried your query I get profit = 613.1578947368421 , Balance_Stock_Quantity = 100, Balance_Stock_Value = 8063.1578947368425, It is not like what I showed in the sample-table. Also it is only of a single product. I need to get a result in product wise as array as array(0=> [product_id= 1], [quantity = 100], [value = 1000][profit = 600], 1 => [product_id = 2], [quantity = 50], [value = 750][profit = 320])

Comment: I have modified the link and query as well. Please go through the link given in my answer with `DEMO` title again. It'll match with your output

Comment: I already stated in my answer that this query return the net values. not the values for each Product. Although, I have added some points as `Notes` in my answer that can help you to achieve your task.

Comment: Success, great answer !!. And I read and liked your suggestion **Note**. But I need to get the same of each product through query. No way?

Comment: If you can afford to create and maintain a table that stores the values given in stock register (2nd Image in your question), then i guess, it can be done easily with a single SQL query.

Comment: Thank you very much